# Create Custom Product in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I need to create the custom product by the **Shopify Storefront**.

Documentation link: http://docs.shopify.com/api/product#create

I have tried the following code:

```
$('#addProduct').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'https://xxxxxx:yyyyyyyyyy@rmisys.myshopify.com/admin/products.json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                  "product": {
                    "title": "Burton Custom Freestlye 151",
                    "body_html": "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
                    "vendor": "Burton",
                    "product_type": "Snowboard",
                    "tags": "Barnes & Noble, John's Fav, \"Big Air\""
                  }
                },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.statusText);
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

The above code shows the following error in Chrome console while ajax request:

> OPTIONS https://rmisys.myshopify.com/admin/products.json 405 (Not Allowed) jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
>   OPTIONS https://rmisys.myshopify.com/admin/products.json No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://rmisys.myshopify.com' is therefore not allowed access. jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://rmisys.myshopify.com/admin/products.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://rmisys.myshopify.com' is therefore not allowed access. design-your-shirt:1
>   error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching for a long time, I found the solution.

The problem is **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing(CORS)**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

This is used to prevent the **CSRF Protection**.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/

In most cases the API should accept requests with **Same Origin Policy**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

So,

If we request from "http" host means, we got the following error for AJAX request from Shopify:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The solution is to redirect the users to "**https**" when they come to our website using the "**http**" protocol.

I tried with the following additional code and successfully added custom products.

```
<script>
window.onload = RedirNonHttps();

function RedirNonHttps() {
    if (location.href.indexOf("https://") == -1) {
        location.href = location.href.replace("http://", "https://");
    }
}
</script>
```

**NOTE:** If we add the custom product from the Client Side with a script it is not secure because keys are then publicly available, the users can do whatever they want with that API key. So make to keep the Secure Auth and then client side script interact with that Secure Auth.

*I hope this answer gives ideas of CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) for beginners.*

Answer (score 2):

Just remember. If you do succeed in figuring out these trivial issues with CORS, you will be exposing your shop to people like me with your API key in public. I will be able to delete all your resources. I can replace your inventory with whatever I want.

You cannot use Javascript like this. It is ridiculous. Create a secure App that authenticates with oAuth properly. Then use your Javascript to talk to that App. Otherwise, you're in for trouble as someone will make you look silly.

Comment: Right? Isn't this what shopify apps and app proxies are supposed to solve?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. It amazes me how many people still don't understand the basics of Javascript. An App Proxy allows you to make safe and secure XHR calls with no CORS issues.